# adapter textview reverting back to old value

Tags: android, android-adapter

i am experiencing a weird and frustrating problem. i want to change the text of a textview based on the value i get from a numberpicker in a baseadapter. i tried to put a value in the textview directly and its working but when i show an alertdialog the textview reverting to the value i put in the xml which is 0. i don't know why it is acting like that.

**UPDATE**

here is the adapter's full code:

```
public class AddOnsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();
DataBaseHelper db;

int txtAddOnId, txtAddOnOperation;

String add_on_name, add_on_price, order_code;
int numPickVal = 0;
private NumberPicker numPicker;

public AddOnsAdapter(Context context,
                     ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
    this.context = context;
    data = arraylist;
    db = new DataBaseHelper(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

private class ViewHolder{
    TextView lblAddOnName, lblPrice, lblQty;
    Button btnModifyAddOn;

    ToggleButton toggleRemove;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_addons_list, parent, false);
    resultp = data.get(position);

    holder.lblAddOnName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtAddOns);
    holder.lblPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPrice);
    holder.lblQty = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtQty);
    holder.btnModifyAddOn = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnQty);
    holder.toggleRemove = (ToggleButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnRemove);

    holder.lblAddOnName.setText(resultp.get("desc"));
    add_on_name = resultp.get("desc");
    holder.lblPrice.setText("₱ " + resultp.get("price"));
    add_on_price = resultp.get("price");
    txtAddOnId = Integer.parseInt(resultp.get("id"));
    txtAddOnOperation = Integer.parseInt(resultp.get("operation"));
    order_code = resultp.get("order_code");

    holder.lblQty.setText("0");

    if(txtAddOnOperation == 1){
        holder.toggleRemove.setEnabled(false);
    }else if(txtAddOnOperation == 2){
        holder.btnModifyAddOn.setEnabled(false);
    }else if(txtAddOnOperation == 3){

    }

    holder.toggleRemove.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                TempOrderAddOn tmpOrderAddon = new TempOrderAddOn();
                tmpOrderAddon.setOrderCode(order_code);
                tmpOrderAddon.setAddOnId(txtAddOnId);
                tmpOrderAddon.setAddOnName(add_on_name);
                tmpOrderAddon.setQty(Integer.parseInt(holder.lblQty.getText().toString()));
                tmpOrderAddon.setAddOnPrice(Double.parseDouble(add_on_price));
                db.addToTempOrderAddOn(tmpOrderAddon);
            } else {
                TempOrderAddOn tmpOrderAddOnDel = new TempOrderAddOn();
                tmpOrderAddOnDel.setAddOnId(txtAddOnId);
                tmpOrderAddOnDel.setOrderCode(order_code);
                db.deleteTempOrderAddOn(tmpOrderAddOnDel);
            }
        }
    });

    holder.btnModifyAddOn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            numPicker = new NumberPicker(context);
            numPicker.setMinValue(0);
            numPicker.setMaxValue(99);
            numPicker.setValue(Integer.parseInt(holder.lblQty.getText().toString()));
            numPicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);

            numPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {

                }
            });

            RelativeLayout relative = new RelativeLayout(context);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams numPickerParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            numPickerParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
            relative.setLayoutParams(params);
            relative.addView(numPicker, numPickerParams);

            holder.lblQty.setText(""+24);

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setTitle("Choose quantity");
            builder.setView(relative);
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    holder.lblQty.setText(""+numPicker.getValue());

                    if(numPicker.getValue() == 0){
                        TempOrderAddOn tmpOrderAddOnDel = new TempOrderAddOn();
                        tmpOrderAddOnDel.setAddOnId(txtAddOnId);
                        tmpOrderAddOnDel.setOrderCode(order_code);
                        db.deleteTempOrderAddOn(tmpOrderAddOnDel);

                        holder.lblQty.setText(""+numPicker.getValue());
                    }else{
                        TempOrderAddOn tmpOrderAddon = new TempOrderAddOn();
                        tmpOrderAddon.setOrderCode(order_code);
                        tmpOrderAddon.setAddOnId(txtAddOnId);
                        tmpOrderAddon.setAddOnName(add_on_name);
                        tmpOrderAddon.setQty(numPicker.getValue());
                        tmpOrderAddon.setAddOnPrice(Double.parseDouble(add_on_price));
                        db.addToTempOrderAddOn(tmpOrderAddon);

                        Log.d("log1","numPickVal: "+numPicker.getValue());
                        holder.lblQty.setText(""+numPicker.getValue());
                    }

                    holder.lblQty.setText(""+numPicker.getValue());
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            AlertDialog dlg = builder.create();
            dlg.show();
        }

    });
    return itemView;
}
```

}

i don't know if this well help but here's the adapter's xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtAddOns"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="34sp"
            android:text="Add On Name"
            style="@style/RobotoTextViewStyle_normal400" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtPrice"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="0"
            style="@style/RobotoTextViewStyle_light300" />


        <TextView
            android:gravity="right"
            android:id="@+id/txtQty"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="0"
            style="@style/RobotoTextViewStyle_light300" />

        <Button
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/btnQty"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.10"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="QTY"
            />

        <ToggleButton
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/btnRemove"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textOn="Remove"
            android:textOff="Remove" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

please help

Comment: please provide full adapter code.

Comment: already added the full adapter code

Comment: As i thought ,your adapter is messed up.

Comment: really, can you please point it out

Comment: Definitely, correcting it. Will test and upload in 5 mins

Comment: Just so you know, You must not use hashmaps in Android

Comment: why? that's what i've learned at work. that's the only way i know how to do data binding.

Comment: Read this completely - https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory.html#DataContainers

Comment: You are supposed to use POJO classes to bind the data.

Comment: And I suggest you to shift to `RecyclerView` from `ListView` since you are having lots of operations on each row. This will just make your code worse in future if you continue using `ListView`.

Comment: thanks @MohammedAtif

Comment: I updated the answer, have look. Its definitely a temporary solution. But it should work.

Comment: thanks again @MohammedAtif, its a very useful to know the fact that showing an alertdialog recreates the adapter. just a last question, is showing something like a toast, because it uses context as well, also recreates the adapter?

Comment: alertdialogues generally have user interaction, so system focus should move on them. Same case with fragments, or rotation of screen. But in case of Toasts, Logs, and other informative texts, system do not require interaction and can display the message wirhout removing the resources from current activity/fragment. And on additional note, use Appkication Context in Toasts which are displayed in Non Ui threads otherwise you will get weird bugs.

Comment: oh i see, thanks a lot again @MohammedAtif. i've learned something new again

Comment: hey @MohammedAtif, it's me again. I'm researching about POJO for android. I can't find a good tutorial right now. do know a good tutorial for it. thanks.

Comment: Hi @Ricky, I wrote a complete blog on RecyclerView, here is the POJO part http://blog.inapptext.com/recyclerview-creating-dynamic-lists-and-grids-in-android-1/#pojo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure whether you are actually planning to

1. Move to POJO class from HashMap.
2. Replace `ListView` with `RecyclerView`

But For time being here is your solution

where ever you are having lines like

```
holder.lblQty.setText(""+0);
```

or

```
holder.lblQty.setText(""+24);
```

replace these lines with

```
resultp.put("Qty", "24");
holder.lblQty.setText(resultp.get("Qty"));
```

or

```
resultp.put("Qty", String.valueOf(numPicker.getValue()));
holder.lblQty.setText(resultp.get("Qty"));
```

Explanation

1. As you said you are using HashMap for Binding the data, but your quantity value was not actually bound.

2. That means you were setting the data on static basis

3. So, whenever you were opening the Alert and closing it, your list refreshes, since data is not bound but given statically, your static data was getting reset to the `TextView`

> Let me know if you need more explanation

Comment: that's what i've been looking for. the reason why the textview reverts to the old text. thanks you very much @MohammedAtif.

Answer (score 0):

Is this your complete code? Try the following!

```
void showDialog() {
DialogFragment newFragment = MyAlertDialogFragment.newInstance(
        R.string..alert_dialog_two_buttons_title);
newFragment.setCancelable(false);
newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
```

}

Comment: thanks your answer, but i think this code is for showing an dialogfragment. that is not my problem though.